# Databinding ComboBox to GraphicsCollection - ESRI, WPF runtime

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, model-view-viewmodel, databinding

I'd like to bind a GraphicsCollection (which is a property in a view model) to a combo box in a XAML window. The problem is I can't figure out how to display attribute values in the combo box. I can get it to display the Geometry property like this:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Geometry"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfGraphics}"  />
```

But I want to be able to do something like this that will display the OBJECTID or some other attribute:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Attributes[&quot;OBJECTID&quot;]"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfGraphics}"  />
```

I also tried this approach - unsuccessfully:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Attributes[0]"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfGraphics}"  />
```

Platform: ArcGIS 10.1, WPF Runtime 10.1.1

**Solution based on Antti Kajanus's answer below:**

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfGraphics}" >
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attributes[OBJECTID]}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Note that the attributite name (OBJECTID) did not have to be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **DisplayMemberPath** property try using **ItemTemplate**. You can access to Attributes collection with binding to **{Binding Attributes[AttributeName]}** in the ItemTemplate.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attributes[Title]}"/>
 </DataTemplate>

<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfGraphics}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
```

I don't have now possibility to test if you can access to attribute from DisplayMemberPath but I remember that I had some issues with that on some point.